# CDI @Inject won't work, object stays null

Tags: java, netbeans, cdi

I am trying to use CDI, using `@Inject` for dependency injection but my object stays `null` and won't initialize... more precisely:
I have a webapplication with `WeatherController` which use a java application with all my modules. In the Java application I have a `ForecastService` where I try to initialize my repositories with CDI without success.
I tried/searched a lot. Hopefully somebody can help me here?

I have a web application which uses this controller:

```
@Path("/weather")
public class WeatherController {
    
    private ForecastService forecastService;
    //private ForecastRepository forecastRepository = new ForecastFakeDB();
    //private ObservationRepository observationRepository = new ObservationFakeDB();

    public WeatherController() {
        //this.forecastService.setForecastRepository(forecastRepository);
        //forecastService.setObservationRepository(observationRepository);
        forecastService  = new ForecastService();
    }
    
    //localhost:8080/DA_project_weatherPredictions/api/weather/observation/Leuven
    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @Path("/observation/{location}")
    public Response getObservation(@PathParam("location") String location) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Observation observation = forecastService.getCurrentObservation(location);
            //Object to JSON in String
            String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(observation);
            return Response.status(200).entity(jsonInString).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly. This is my forecastService:

```
public class ForecastService implements Service {
    
    @Inject
    ForecastRepository forecastRepository;

    @Inject
    ObservationRepository observationRepository;
    
    private Client client;
    private WebTarget webTargetObservation, webTargetForecast;
    
    public ForecastService() {
//        WeatherRepositoryFactory weatherRepositoryFactory = new WeatherRepositoryFactory();
//        forecastRepository = weatherRepositoryFactory.getForecastRepository(repository);
//        observationRepository = weatherRepositoryFactory.getObservationRepository(repository);
        loadWeather();
    }    
    
    public void setForecastRepository(ForecastRepository forecastRepository) {
        this.forecastRepository = forecastRepository;
    }
    
    public void setObservationRepository(ObservationRepository observationRepository) {
        this.observationRepository = observationRepository;
    }    
    
    public void loadWeather() {
        //http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&appid=12fa8f41738b72d954b6758d48e129aa&q=BE,Leuven
        //http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?units=metric&appid=12fa8f41738b72d954b6758d48e129aa&q=BE,Leuven
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTargetObservation = client.target("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather")
            .queryParam("mode", "json")
            .queryParam("units", "metric")
            .queryParam("appid", "12fa8f41738b72d954b6758d48e129aa");
        webTargetForecast = client.target("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast")
            .queryParam("mode", "json")
            .queryParam("units", "metric")
            .queryParam("appid", "12fa8f41738b72d954b6758d48e129aa");        
    }

    public Observation getCurrentObservation(String location) throws Exception {
        Observation observation;
        observation = observationRepository.getObservation(location);
        if (observation == null) {
            try {
                //observation = webTargetObservation.queryParam("q", location).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Observation.class);
                Response response = webTargetObservation.queryParam("q", location).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
                String json = response.readEntity(String.class);
                //System.out.println(json);
                response.close();
                observation = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Observation.class);
                //System.out.println(observation.getWeather().getDescription());
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(e.toString());
                for (StackTraceElement ste : e.getStackTrace()) {
                    sb.append("\n\tat ");
                    sb.append(ste);
                }
                String trace = sb.toString();
                throw new Exception (trace);
                //throw new Exception("Location not found");
            }
            this.observationRepository.addObservation(observation, location);
        }
        return observation;
    }
```

So the problem is that my repositories stay `null`

```
@Alternative
public class ObservationDB implements ObservationRepository{
    
    //as ID we can use the ASCI value of the String key .. example uklondon to ASCII
    
    public ObservationDB(String name) {
    
    }   
    
    @Override
    public Observation getObservation(String location) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void addObservation(Observation observation, String location) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
    
}
```

Mermory DB:

```
@Default
public class ObservationFakeDB implements ObservationRepository {

    //example String key : beleuven, uklondon
    private static Map<String, Observation> observations;

    public ObservationFakeDB() {
        observations = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Observation getObservation(String location) {
        return observations.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void addObservation(Observation observation, String location) {
        observations.put(location, observation);
    }
}
```

I have a beans.xml, I thought beans.xml, `@Inject`, `@Default` en `@Alternative` would make this work. I tried `@Dependent`, `@Applicationscoped`.

[image: Here my map structure:]

EDIT:
I also often get this warning on Netbeans.

[image]

My beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">

</beans>
```

Comment: have you tried to simply annotate the field `forecastService` with `@Inject` instead of creating it yourself ?

Comment: also remove `loadWeather()` from the default constructor of `ForecastService` and simply annotate it with `@Inject` to indicate the CDI container to call it on init

Comment: What do you call "my repositories" ?

Comment: If I try @Inject on forecastService I got this: "Unsatisfied dependencies for type Service with qualifiers @Default" I amtrying first to get the other thing to work and later on this need to be injected to indeed.

Comment: My repositories are my database classes, real DB or fake (memory) DB

Comment: add your `beans.xml`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto here you go

Comment: I've just tested your code with weld 2.4, adding `@Inject` on the field `forecastService` of `WeatherController` was enough to make it work properly Which CDI implementation do you use?

Comment: Its this "<groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>"  But I tried it again, I don't know how but now it worked. Thanks alot mate !!! One thing that is different now is that my beans.xml file is now blue dot instead of the same look as a xml. Maybe it is now recognized as a beans xml file ...

Comment: I still need to change some things, but man I have searched alot for this. I am very thankfull, thanks alot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let your **CDI container** manages the lifecycle of **all** your beans to allow it to resolve and inject properly their dependencies.

So, in your case you should not create yourself the instance of `ForecastService`, you should rather delegate it to the **CDI container** by simply annotating the field `forecastService` with `@Inject` this way its dependencies will be automatically resolved and set by the container.

```
public class WeatherController {

    @Inject
    private ForecastService forecastService;

    ...
```